# Android : I cant' create Application Key when using Xtify for push notification

Tags: android, xtify

I want my application should support almost all android versons. So I planned to use Xtify. They asked to submit app details to generate an Application Key.

But when I am submitting the form for creating Application Key, nothing is happening. And the form is still remains there. Does anybody face the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should follow the implementation guide : http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/2.x+Series+Implementation+Guides

it is really good and actually it worked for me